# Find Project locations in Project Explorer (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project-explorer

I've added a button in the context menu to execute only when you right click in the Project Explorer window. I want to be able to grab each project in the Project Explorer window and grab the ProjectName and ProjectLocation and put that into an object by itself and return the new array of objects.

I can't find a way to access the information that I need.

plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu">
      <command commandId="helloworld.sample"
        label="Hello World" style="push">
      </command>
    </menuContribution>
  </extension>
  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command defaultHandler="helloworld.handler.samplehandler"
      id="helloworld.sample" name="Sample">
    </command>
  </extension>
```

samplehandler.java

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IWorkbenchPart viewpart  = page.findView("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer");

Tree tree = (Tree) ((TreeViewer) viewpart.getSite().getSelectionProvider()).getControl(); 
TreeItem[] selTree = tree.getSelection();
```

I feel as though tree or selTree would have the information I want but I can't find it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selection data from the selection provider:

```
IStructuredSelection sel =   
     (IStructuredSelection)viewpart.getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection(); 

Object selObj = sel.getFirstElement();

IProject project =
   (IProject)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(selObj, IProject.class);

... might return null if selection is not the project

String name = project.getName();

IPath location = project.getLocation();
```

To get all the projects use:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin().getWorkspace();

IProject [] projects = workspace.getRoot().getProjects();
```

Comment: While this did answer the majority of my question, I realize I may not have been specific enough with what I wanted as a result. I'm looking to get the name and location of ALL the projects that are displayed in the projectExplorer view. Using this solution only allows the selected project info to be displayed.

Comment: Yes, while right now i'm doing it with a right click, I figure i can transfer the code to another method like a menu button click or something. But yes I need to get all the projects in the current workspace aka all projects in project explorer window